# Problema com o toFixed e casas decimas

Tags: javascript

Meu código lê o valor com uma casa decimal, porém o `toFixed(1)` transforma a variavel `A` em string:

```js
function VerificaNota(){
 let x = 0
 let valor = parseFloat(prompt('Digite a nota do aluno'));
  while(x < 1) {
    if(valor >= 0 && valor <= 10) {   
      x++;
      return parseFloat(valor)
    }
    else {
      valor = prompt();
    } 
  }
}

let A = VerificaNota();
A = A.toFixed(1);
alert(A)
let soma = A + A;
alert(soma);
```

Comment: Sim, o `.toFixed` converte em _String_. Não é isso que queres? qual é a ideia de usar o `.toFixed`?  é para arredondar as décimas?

Comment: Porque estou resolvendo um exercício aonde A deve ler um valor com uma casa decimal, então se eu digito 1, A deve recever 1.0 entendeu?

Comment: Ok, vais comparar mais notas ou queres só converter a nota que é recebida no `prompt` e mostrar com 1 casa decimal?

Answer (score 4):

Primeiramente, alguns detalhes na sua função que lê a nota. Primeiro você faz:

```
let valor = parseFloat(prompt('Digite a nota do aluno'))
```

Ou seja, `valor` será um número (pois [é isso que `parseFloat` retorna](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#Return_value)). Depois, dentro do `while`, você faz:

```
return parseFloat(valor)
```

Ou seja, você tenta converter um número para um número. Mas `valor` já é um número (pois o `return` está dentro do `if` que já verificou se o valor é válido), então não precisa chamar `parseFloat` novamente. Basta retornar `valor` diretamente.

Outro detalhe é a lógica do *loop*. Não precisa dessa variável `x` para saber se você deve continuar pedindo para digitar um número válido, basta fazer algo assim:

```js
function lerNota() {
    while (true) {
        let valor = parseFloat(prompt('Digite a nota do aluno'));
        if (valor >= 0 && valor <= 10) {   
            return valor;
        } else alert('Nota deve ser um número entre 0 e 10');
    } 
}

let nota = lerNota();
console.log(nota);
```

Se o valor estiver entre 0 e 10, retorna. Senão, exibe uma mensagem e pede que o usuário digite novamente a nota. O `return` retorna o valor e sai da função, interrompendo o *loop*.

Se não for digitado um número (por exemplo, se o usuário digitar `"abc"`), `parseFloat` retorna [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), e como este é um valor especial que [não é maior, igual, nem menor que qualquer número](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26982925), não entrará no `if`, então a função também já verifica quando não é digitado um número.

---

Agora vamos ao cálculo em si. Entendi que você quer calcular o dobro da nota digitada, e mostrar o resultado com apenas uma casa decimal.

Vi que você quer que a nota digitada também tenha apenas uma casa decimal. Uma opção é usar [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), que transforma-a em `string`, e em seguida transformar esta string em número novamente, como já foi feito [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416047/112052) (embora também seja possível apenas fazendo alguns cálculos, como veremos no final).

Mas tem um detalhe, `toFixed` pode ou não arredondar o valor, dependendo do caso:

```js
function arredonda(n) {
    console.log(`${n} => ${n.toFixed(1)}`);
}

arredonda(1.47); // 1.5
arredonda(1.44); // 1.4
```

Ou seja, se o usuário digitar `"1.47"`, a nota será transformada em `1.5`, e o dobro dela será `3`. Mas se a ideia era não arredondar o valor original, então a nota deveria ser transformada em `1.4`, e o dobro seria `2.8`. **Qual dessas opções você quer**?

Independente da opção, você não precisa usar `toFixed` para transformar em string, para depois converter para número novamente. Basta fazer alguns cálculos: multiplique por 10, arredonde (ou não) e divida por 10.

Existe ainda outra possibilidade: não eliminar as casas decimais da nota, e só fazer isso no resultado final. Nesse caso também pode dar diferença, pois o dobro de `1.47` é `2.94`. E se aplicarmos `toFixed(1)` neste valor, o resultado será `2.9`.

Ou seja, 3 resultados diferentes, dependendo de como você tratar os dados. No código abaixo podemos ver essas 3 opções:

```js
// 1.47 se torna 1.5
function arredonda(valor) {
    // poderia ser parseFloat(valor.toFixed(1)), mas preferi fazer contas :-)
    return Math.round(valor * 10) / 10;
}

// 1.47 se torna 1.4
function naoArredonda(valor) {
    return Math.floor(valor * 10) / 10;
}

// dobra o número e aplica toFixed (que arredonda o resultado)
function dobro(valor) {
    return (2 * valor).toFixed(1);
}

let nota = 1.47;

// arredonda a nota e calcula o dobro
console.log(dobro(arredonda(nota))); // 3.0

// pega somente a primeira casa decimal, sem arredondar, e calcula o dobro
console.log(dobro(naoArredonda(nota))); // 2.8

// preserva as casas decimais da nota, e aplica toFixed somente no dobro
console.log(dobro(nota)); // 2.9
```

Ao calcular o dobro, eu usei `toFixed` no resultado, mas você também pode usar os outros métodos (arredondando ou não) para exibir o dobro da maneira que achar melhor.